# Performance tuning of Informatica mapping

Tags: sql, sql-server, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have to tune the informatica mapping performance .Source and target is sql server table. Mapping contain SQ-unconnected lookup-exp-target. Source and target table is same. 
 Lookup query is taking 7-8mins in database And as per the session log also lookup cache creation is taking time.
I can see in this , It is taking time while creating the lookup cache , but I am not able to get the exact issue.

Can you please suggest how tune this session log or lookup query

Below  is the session log :-

```
Severity    Timestamp   Node    Thread  Message Code    Message
INFO    1/2/2020 2:38:17 AM WRITER_1_*_1    WRT_8158    

*****START LOAD SESSION*****

Load Start Time: Thu Jan 02 02:38:17 2020

Target tables:

     Dim_Cust_Ord


INFO    1/2/2020 2:38:17 AM WRITER_1_*_1    WRT_8005    Writer run started.
INFO    1/2/2020 2:38:17 AM READER_1_1_1    RR_4049 RR_4049 SQL Query issued to database : (Thu Jan 02 02:38:17 2020)
INFO    1/2/2020 2:38:17 AM READER_1_1_1    RR_4029 SQ Instance [SQ_Dim_Cust_Ord] User specified SQL Query [SELECT 
DISTINCT Dim_Cust_Ord.Business_Unit, 
Dim_Cust_Ord.PO_Num,
Dim_Cust_Ord.Account_Num 
FROM 
Dim_Cust_Ord Dim_Cust_Ord with(NOLOCK)
WHERE 
(Dim_Cust_Ord.PO_IND IS NULL OR Dim_Cust_Ord.PO_IND='O') 
AND Dim_Cust_Ord.Business_Unit IN ('C','W','R','U')]
INFO    1/2/2020 2:38:17 AM     WRITER_1_*_1    WRT_8270    Target connection group #1 consists of target(s) [Dim_Cust_Ord]
INFO    1/2/2020 2:38:17 AM WRITER_1_*_1    WRT_8003    Writer initialization complete.
INFO    1/2/2020 2:38:17 AM READER_1_1_1    BLKR_16007  Reader run started.
INFO    1/2/2020 2:38:19 AM READER_1_1_1    RR_4050 RR_4050 First row returned from database to reader : (Thu Jan 02 02:38:19 2020)
INFO    1/2/2020 2:38:19 AM LKPDP_1 TM_6660 Total Buffer Pool size is 609824 bytes and Block size is 65536 bytes.
INFO    1/2/2020 2:38:19 AM LKPDP_1:READER_1_1  DBG_21438   Reader: Source is [BIPAOSQL@SLM], user [informat]
INFO    1/2/2020 2:38:19 AM LKPDP_1:READER_1_1  BLKR_16007  Reader run started.
INFO    1/2/2020 2:38:19 AM LKPDP_1:READER_1_1  BLKR_16003  Initialization completed successfully.
INFO    1/2/2020 2:38:20 AM LKPDP_1:READER_1_1  RR_4049 RR_4049 SQL Query issued to database : (Thu Jan 02 02:38:20 2020)
INFO    1/2/2020 2:41:49 AM LKPDP_1:READER_1_1  RR_4050 RR_4050 First row returned from database to reader : (Thu Jan 02 02:41:49 2020)
INFO    1/2/2020 2:41:49 AM LKPDP_1:TRANSF_1_1  DBG_21079   DBG_21079 Creating Lookup Cache : (Thu Jan 02 02:41:49 2020)
INFO    1/2/2020 2:41:49 AM LKPDP_1:TRANSF_1_1  TT_11195    Warning: Unsorted input found when building the cache for the Lookup transformation [LKP_FACT_BOOK]. The current number of entries in the index cache is 2. For optimal performance, use sorted input.

INFO    1/2/2020 2:59:16 AM LKPDP_1:READER_1_1  BLKR_16008  Reader run completed.
INFO    1/2/2020 2:59:16 AM LKPDP_1:TRANSF_1_1  DBG_21641   LKP_FACT_BOOK: Index cache size = [178960000], Data cache size = [357916672]
INFO    1/2/2020 2:59:16 AM LKPDP_1:TRANSF_1_1  DBG_21297   Lookup cache row count : 30101473

INFO    1/2/2020 2:59:16 AM LKPDP_1:TRANSF_1_1  DBG_21294   DBG_21294 Lookup cache creation completed : (Thu Jan 02 02:59:16 2020)
INFO    1/2/2020 2:59:16 AM LKPDP_1:TRANSF_1_1  DBG_21682   Lookup table row count : 30101473
INFO    1/2/2020 2:59:16 AM LKPDP_1:TRANSF_1_1  DBG_21216   Finished transformations for Source Qualifier [LKP_FACT_BOOK{{DSQ}}]. Total errors [0] 
INFO    1/2/2020 2:59:16 AM LKPDP_1:TRANSF_1_1  CMN_1671    Created new cache files testlokup_4_0_278W64.[dat/idx] in directory F:\Informatica\InfoCache for Lookup [LKP_FACT_BOOK].
INFO    1/2/2020 2:59:17 AM WRITER_1_*_1    WRT_8167    Start loading table [Dim_Cust_Ord] at: Thu Jan 02 02:59:16 2020
INFO    1/2/2020 2:59:36 AM WRITER_1_*_1    WRT_8161    
TARGET BASED COMMIT POINT  Thu Jan 02 02:59:35 2020
===================================================

WRT_8036 Target: Dim_Cust_Ord (Instance Name: [Dim_Cust_Ord])
WRT_8041 Updated rows  - Requested: 10296      Applied: 10296      Rejected: 0          Affected: 25585     

Severity    Timestamp   Node    Thread  Message Code    Message
INFO    1/2/2020 2:59:53 AM WRITER_1_*_1    WRT_8161    
TARGET BASED COMMIT POINT  Thu Jan 02 02:59:52 2020
===================================================

WRT_8036 Target: Dim_Cust_Ord (Instance Name: [Dim_Cust_Ord])
WRT_8041 Updated rows  - Requested: 20592      Applied: 20592      Rejected: 0          Affected: 49811     

INFO    1/2/2020 3:00:13 AM WRITER_1_*_1    WRT_8161    
TARGET BASED COMMIT POINT  Thu Jan 02 03:00:12 2020
===================================================

WRT_8036 Target: Dim_Cust_Ord (Instance Name: [Dim_Cust_Ord])
WRT_8041 Updated rows  - Requested: 30888      Applied: 30888      Rejected: 0          Affected: 74052     

INFO    1/2/2020 3:00:34 AM WRITER_1_*_1    WRT_8161    
TARGET BASED COMMIT POINT  Thu Jan 02 03:00:34 2020
===================================================

WRT_8036 Target: Dim_Cust_Ord (Instance Name: [Dim_Cust_Ord])
WRT_8041 Updated rows  - Requested: 41184      Applied: 41184      Rejected: 0          Affected: 101520    

INFO    1/2/2020 3:00:56 AM WRITER_1_*_1    WRT_8161    
TARGET BASED COMMIT POINT  Thu Jan 02 03:00:56 2020
===================================================

WRT_8036 Target: Dim_Cust_Ord (Instance Name: [Dim_Cust_Ord])
WRT_8041 Updated rows  - Requested: 51480      Applied: 51480      Rejected: 0          Affected: 129791    

INFO    1/2/2020 3:01:18 AM WRITER_1_*_1    WRT_8161    
TARGET BASED COMMIT POINT  Thu Jan 02 03:01:18 2020
===================================================

WRT_8036 Target: Dim_Cust_Ord (Instance Name: [Dim_Cust_Ord])
WRT_8041 Updated rows  - Requested: 61776      Applied: 61776      Rejected: 0          Affected: 157788    

INFO    1/2/2020 3:01:41 AM WRITER_1_*_1    WRT_8161    
TARGET BASED COMMIT POINT  Thu Jan 02 03:01:41 2020
===================================================

WRT_8036 Target: Dim_Cust_Ord (Instance Name: [Dim_Cust_Ord])
WRT_8041 Updated rows  - Requested: 72072      Applied: 72072      Rejected: 0          Affected: 189511    

INFO    1/2/2020 3:02:05 AM WRITER_1_*_1    WRT_8161    
TARGET BASED COMMIT POINT  Thu Jan 02 03:02:05 2020
===================================================

WRT_8036 Target: Dim_Cust_Ord (Instance Name: [Dim_Cust_Ord])
WRT_8041 Updated rows  - Requested: 82368      Applied: 82368      Rejected: 0          Affected: 215331    

INFO    1/2/2020 3:02:23 AM WRITER_1_*_1    WRT_8161    
TARGET BASED COMMIT POINT  Thu Jan 02 03:02:23 2020
===================================================

WRT_8036 Target: Dim_Cust_Ord (Instance Name: [Dim_Cust_Ord])
WRT_8041 Updated rows  - Requested: 92664      Applied: 92664      Rejected: 0          Affected: 243820    

INFO    1/2/2020 3:02:47 AM WRITER_1_*_1    WRT_8161    
TARGET BASED COMMIT POINT  Thu Jan 02 03:02:47 2020
===================================================

WRT_8036 Target: Dim_Cust_Ord (Instance Name: [Dim_Cust_Ord])
WRT_8041 Updated rows  - Requested: 102960     Applied: 102960     Rejected: 0          Affected: 271753    

INFO    1/2/2020 3:03:11 AM WRITER_1_*_1    WRT_8161    
TARGET BASED COMMIT POINT  Thu Jan 02 03:03:10 2020
===================================================

WRT_8036 Target: Dim_Cust_Ord (Instance Name: [Dim_Cust_Ord])
WRT_8041 Updated rows  - Requested: 113256     Applied: 113256     Rejected: 0          Affected: 297470    

INFO    1/2/2020 3:03:35 AM WRITER_1_*_1    WRT_8161    
TARGET BASED COMMIT POINT  Thu Jan 02 03:03:34 2020
===================================================

WRT_8036 Target: Dim_Cust_Ord (Instance Name: [Dim_Cust_Ord])
WRT_8041 Updated rows  - Requested: 123552     Applied: 123552     Rejected: 0          Affected: 324556    

INFO    1/2/2020 3:03:59 AM WRITER_1_*_1    WRT_8161    
TARGET BASED COMMIT POINT  Thu Jan 02 03:03:59 2020
===================================================

WRT_8036 Target: Dim_Cust_Ord (Instance Name: [Dim_Cust_Ord])
WRT_8041 Updated rows  - Requested: 133848     Applied: 133848     Rejected: 0          Affected: 351867    

INFO    1/2/2020 3:04:25 AM WRITER_1_*_1    WRT_8161    
TARGET BASED COMMIT POINT  Thu Jan 02 03:04:24 2020
===================================================

WRT_8036 Target: Dim_Cust_Ord (Instance Name: [Dim_Cust_Ord])
WRT_8041 Updated rows  - Requested: 144144     Applied: 144144     Rejected: 0          Affected: 377844    

INFO    1/2/2020 3:04:34 AM READER_1_1_1    BLKR_16008  Reader run completed.
INFO    1/2/2020 3:04:34 AM READER_1_1_1    BLKR_16019  Read [158430] rows, read [0] error rows for source table [Dim_Cust_Ord] instance name [Dim_Cust_Ord]
INFO    1/2/2020 3:04:39 AM TRANSF_1_1_1    DBG_21216   Finished transformations for Source Qualifier [SQ_Dim_Cust_Ord]. Total errors [0] 
INFO    1/2/2020 3:04:43 AM WRITER_1_*_1    WRT_8161    
TARGET BASED COMMIT POINT  Thu Jan 02 03:04:43 2020
===================================================

WRT_8036 Target: Dim_Cust_Ord (Instance Name: [Dim_Cust_Ord])
WRT_8041 Updated rows  - Requested: 154440     Applied: 154440     Rejected: 0          Affected: 401641    

INFO    1/2/2020 3:04:48 AM WRITER_1_*_1    WRT_8168    End loading table [Dim_Cust_Ord] at: Thu Jan 02 03:04:47 2020
INFO    1/2/2020 3:04:48 AM WRITER_1_*_1    WRT_8035    Load complete time: Thu Jan 02 03:04:47 2020

LOAD SUMMARY
============

WRT_8036 Target: Dim_Cust_Ord (Instance Name: [Dim_Cust_Ord])
WRT_8041 Updated rows  - Requested: 158430     Applied: 158430     Rejected: 0          Affected: 412362    


INFO    1/2/2020 3:04:48 AM WRITER_1_*_1    WRT_8141    
Commit on end-of-data  Thu Jan 02 03:04:47 2020
===================================================

WRT_8036 Target: Dim_Cust_Ord (Instance Name: [Dim_Cust_Ord])
WRT_8041 Updated rows  - Requested: 158430     Applied: 158430     Rejected: 0          Affected: 412362    

INFO    1/2/2020 3:04:48 AM MANAGER PETL_24031  
***** RUN INFO FOR TGT LOAD ORDER GROUP [1], CONCURRENT SET [1] *****
Thread [READER_1_1_1] created for [the read stage] of partition point [SQ_Dim_Cust_Ord] has completed.
    Total Run Time = [1577.617025] secs
    Total Idle Time = [1574.481379] secs
    Busy Percentage = [0.198758]
Thread [TRANSF_1_1_1] created for [the transformation stage] of partition point [SQ_Dim_Cust_Ord] has completed.
    Total Run Time = [1579.801052] secs
    Total Idle Time = [1574.840183] secs
    Busy Percentage = [0.314019]
    Thread work time breakdown:
        EXP_DIM_CUST_ORD: 100.000000 percent
Thread [WRITER_1_*_1] created for [the write stage] of partition point [Dim_Cust_Ord] has completed.
    Total Run Time = [1531.502834] secs
    Total Idle Time = [1199.889383] secs
    Busy Percentage = [21.652813]

INFO    1/2/2020 3:04:48 AM WRITER_1_*_1    WRT_8043    *****END LOAD SESSION*****
INFO    1/2/2020 3:04:48 AM WRITER_1_*_1    WRT_8006    Writer run completed.
```

Lookup Query :-

````
SELECT 
SUM(Fact_Book.Qty) as Qty, 
Fact_Book.Num as Num, 
Fact_Book.Sold_To as bookSTo, 
(case when Fact_Book.bk_numbr = '50'
then 'C'
when Fact_Book.bk_numbr = '40'
then 'R'
when Fact_Book.bk_numbr = '98'
then 'U'
else 'W'
end ) as code
FROM 
Fact_Book with(NOLOCK)
GROUP BY
Fact_Book.Num,
Fact_Book.bookSTo ,
(case when Fact_Book.bk_numbr = '50'
then 'C'
when Fact_Book.bk_numbr = '40'
then 'R'
when Fact_Book.bk_numbr = '98'
then 'U'
else 'W'
end )```
````

Answer (score 0):

If the source and target is the same physical table and lookup uses the same database, you can take advantage of `Pushdown Optimization` - just enable it in session properties and set it to `Full`.

If that's not possible, try changing lookup to joiner, sort data on `Source Qualifier` appropriately and enable the `Sorted input` joiner property.

Let me know if there would be any issues - there are some more options available.

Answer (score 0):

I see that your lookup is caching around 30 million records with a group by clause in the query with no sorted input. Lookup will group the data and process it only after caching the entire data set. That's the main reason for taking a lot of time. You can try sorting the columns used in group by in the same order either in SQ or by creating a sorter. If you do not see any improvement after that, pass the sorted data and then try removing the cache option from lookup , some times not caching your lookup works faster than caching it. Also, what is the order by generated by the integration service? have only few columns in order by or suppress it altogether with '--' at the end of query. Indexing the lookup condition columns in the same order will also help improving the performance.

Answer (score 0):

Using such a lookup query is rarely a good idea. Performance-wise I would try the following two options:
1. source the LKP table and build a mapping to create the expected LKP cache contents as the target (either flat file or DB table).
2. Source the LKP Table, use some AGG and/or JNR to implement that logic, and then join this data stream with your actual source data using a Joiner transformation.

Using AGG and JNR performs best if you make sure that these transformation receive sorted input. The Sorter transformation is the best tool to ensure sorted input for all transformations in PowerCenter (DB sorts often sort strings according to their locale which makes them "wrongly sorted" from the PowerCenter perspective).